# How do I create code snippets for vscode for "print_r" that outputs the contents of the variable passed to it, along with the filename ,line number

Tags: php, debugging, phpdebugbar

How do I create code snippets for vscode for "print_r" that outputs the contents of the variable passed to it, along with the filename and line number of the file where the function is called and Also want proper format print in output screen.

```
$data = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
print_r($data);
```

I want output Like this :
Myname FileNmae lineNumber data

[image: sample output image]

Comment: you must have tried something yourself too?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it. You need to pass your name as parameter to the function:

```
function printCustom($name)
{
    $data = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    print_r(
        $name ." ". basename(__FILE__) ." ". __LINE__." \n data :: "
    );

    print_r($data);
}


printCustom('Grimma');
```

Here is a working screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @msrajwat298 - why have you completely rewritten this answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated something because she wanted VSCode snippets. I must have made a mistake. Can you please let me know how I can fix it?